# Present participle + being usage. Is it ok?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, american-english, british-english, present-continuous

Is everything OK grammatically in this sentence?

> We are being wise, to make that decision.

Comment: I would rephrase that as `We are wise to make that decision`, `It is wise of us to make that decision`, or `That is a wise decision for us`. Out of the 3, I think the last one sounds best as a native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence bothers me as-is.  I am not 100% certain if the grammar is correct or not, but the comma seems misplaced and the use of the infinitive to make instead of using 'making' feels wrong.  Instead, trying to maintain the exact same tense:

> We are being wise in making that decision.
>
> For us, making that decision now is wise.

It is slightly awkward to put this in the present progressive.  If I were trying to convey this, I would use something like Nicholas Clark suggested:

> That would be a wise decision.

And omit the "for us" if possible and let the listener infer it from context.